# running multiple terminal comands on vm in sequence

Tags: python, ubuntu

```
nohup scrapy crawl test -o fed.csv &
nohup scrapy crawl test -o feder.csv &
nohup scrapy crawl fullrun -o dez.csv &
```

Hello, How can I run the following commands in sequence (when the first one finishes,the next one gets executed) on Virtual machine (Ubuntu terminal)

I wasn't sure if to ask this question on [askubuntu.com](http://askubunto.com) or here, I hope this is correct place to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run commands one by one and only when the previous one completed successfully you can use :

```
command1 && command2
```

if your commands are independent of each other then you can use:

```
command1; command2
```

Comment: thanks, but to make sure this line here `command1; command2` make them run simultaneously  but this `command1 && command2` wait for execution to finish on first to go on to the next right

Comment: Both commands wait for the previous one to complete but in case of `&&` command will only execute when the previous one executed without error and with `;`  it is going to execute anyway

Comment: and by ```error``` , bash detects if  the command exit status  equals 0,  0 is success otherwise failure. not every python script  follows this rule.